# JTable renders removed JButton instead of a new one

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

The program in general is 3 arrays of a custom objects , with a JTable representing each array. I have a custom renderer and tablemodel. The custom object has inside it an object which is every visual element.

When I remove a row from 1 table and replace , rerender it as it is empty it renders perfectly , but when I add a new row to the table it renders properly JTextField and JLabel , but renders JButtons from previous object.

Table model

```
public class PositionTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
private List<kosilkshik.Position> local;
public PositionTableModel(List<kosilkshik.Position> list)
{
    local = list;
}
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
{
    return true;
}
@Override
public int getRowCount(){return local.size();}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {return 24;}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
{
    kosilkshik.Position pos = local.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) 
    {
        case 0:
            return pos.view.symbols.get(0);
        case 1:
            return pos.view.ratios.get(0);
        case 2:
            return pos.view.symbols.get(1);
        case 3:
            return pos.view.ratios.get(1);
        case 4:
            if(pos.view.symbols.size()>2)
            {
                return pos.view.symbols.get(2);
            }else{return null;}
        case 5:
            if(pos.view.symbols.size()>2)
            {
                return pos.view.ratios.get(2);
            }else{return null;}
        case 6:
            if(pos.view.symbols.size()>3)
            {
                return pos.view.symbols.get(3);
            }else{return null;}
        case 7:
            if(pos.view.symbols.size()>3)
            {
                return pos.view.ratios.get(3);
            }else{return null;}
        case 8:
            return pos.view.name;
        case 9:
            return pos.view.qt;
        case 10:
            return pos.view.current;
        case 11:
            return pos.view.buy;
        case 12:
            return pos.view.sell;
        case 13:
            return pos.view.bid;
        case 14:
            return pos.view.avg;
        case 15:
            return pos.view.ask;
        case 16:
            return pos.view.mkt;
        case 17:
            return pos.view.p;
        case 18:
            return pos.view.flip;
        case 19:
            return pos.view.invert;
        case 20:
            return pos.view.control;
        case 21:
            return pos.view.control1;
        case 22:
            return pos.view.control2;
        case 23:
            return pos.view.control3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

}

TableRender does not have any caching manually added.

Method for removing rows from table

```
 AbstractTableModel m =(AbstractTableModel)tableS.getModel();
 m.fireTableRowsDeleted(row,row);
```

Method for inserting rows:

```
AbstractTableModel m =(AbstractTableModel)tableS.getModel();
m.fireTableRowsInserted(0, suggested.size()-1);
```

Comment: What does your renderer look like? And are you aware that a component painted by a renderer is just a "rubber stamp" and is not clickable, etc?

Comment: http://pastebin.ru/pOH9KlFy Renderer source.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  And post it as an edit.  External links go stale, and few people will follow them even when they are current.

Answer (score 1):

> Method for removing rows from table...,
>
> Method for inserting rows...

Those two methods should be part of the custom TableModel, not part of your application code. It is the responsibility of the TableModel to notify the table when the data changes. So you need to create method for you model like "addRow(...)" and "removeRow(...)".

Make sure the "row" values you pass to the fireXXX methods are correct. The DefaultTableModel implements addRow(...) and removeRow(...) method, so check out the source code of the DefaultTableModel to see how that code works.